# what is different between boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::cancel and socket::close

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

According to boost documentation, when  `socket::close()` is invoked, asynchronous send, receive or connect operations will be cancelled immediately, and will complete with the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

`socket::cancel` causes all outstanding asynchronous connect, send and receive operations to finish immediately, and the handlers for cancelled operations will be passed the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

Is there some difference between them?

When I want to finish one socket connection, which one should I call such that their callback handler will be invoked with `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there some difference between them?

Yes. The `close()` method closes the socket, while the `cancel()` method cancels outstanding asynchonous operations. Using `cancel()` does not close the socket.

> When I want to finish one socket
>   connection, which one I should to call?

You should use `cancel()` to stop any outstanding asynchronous operations. The socket will be closed by its destructor.

Comment: so if i use close and not cancel,there are some problems? close function can close the socket,and any outstanding asynchronous operations is stopped by returnning boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error,why i should use cancel instead of close.i worry if some asynchronous operations is executing,the cancel could not cancel it,yes? like asio::ip::tcp::resolve::cancel,i try many time to cancel the resolve_handler after calling async_resolve ,but resolve_handler alway return with no boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error.i think resolve_handler has being executing?yes?

Comment: @xiao there are no problems using close if you intend to close the socket. I suggest you ask additional questions about async_resolve. If my answer has helped you, please accept it.